# What is the meaning of the phrase "registering a callback" with Python APIs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get into the details about how Python 3 APIs are designed, when adding elements to an UI using APIs from modules available inside applications that offer a python 3.x interpreter I'm asked to register a callback in order to be able to use my functions/scripts: what does "registering a callback" means from the Cpython's point of view ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

typically, it means that you create a function:

```
def foo(some,arguments):
    pass #do something here
```

and then you pass that function to some class in the provided API:

```
API_class_instance.register_callback(foo)
```

Now the `API_class_instance` will call `foo` under the documented circumstances.

Comment: and what is the purpose of passing foo ? register() knows the type of foo() ? Since there is no real concept of type under Python I'm wondering the point of this ? Basically I can throw anything inside register() at this point.

Comment: @user2244984 -- register doesn't need to know the `type` of `foo`.  As long as it can *call* foo according to the documented API, then it's fine.  However, if you do `API_class_instance.register_callback(2)`, then you'll probably have problems when `API_class_instance` actually wants to *call* the callback (since here we passed an uncallable callback)

Comment: so basically there is no filter or real criteria for what I can feed to register(), and "if my script doesn't crash" is _probably_ fine ?

Comment: @user2244984 Python is a **strongly typed** language, there definitely *is* a concept of type. A function is an instance of the `FunctionType`. It's not like C where every different signature is considered a different type, but that's a detail. By they way: there are ways to know how many arguments a callable accept and other information, but these are seldom used, since they don't provide much benefits, go against python philosophy and they increase code complexity.

Answer (score 8):

[Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29):

> In computer programming, a callback is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a synchronous callback or it might happen at later time, as in an asynchronous callback.

So, if you are registering a callback to a UI API then you are likely passing some function that you created to another function which will be responsible for calling your function when some condition occurs.

For example you might have a button in the UI and you want to execute some code when that button is clicked.  You might register a callback that looks something like this:

```
def onclick():
    print 'Button clicked!'

# call the onclick() method when the 'click' event happens on the button
some_api.register_callback(button, 'click', onclick)
```

And the API code might look something like this:

```
# global variable containing callbacks
callbacks = {}

# API for registering callbacks
def register_callback(obj, event, callback):
    if obj not in callbacks:
        callbacks[obj] = {}
    callbacks[obj][event] = callback

# a function that is called when some event is triggered on an object
def process_event(obj, event):
    if obj in callbacks and event in callbacks[obj]:
        # this object/event pair has a callback, call it
        callback = callbacks[obj][event]
        callback()
```

Comment: what about if the APIs are C modules ? How to implement an async callback in C/C++ ?

Comment: Are you asking how the API would call the function that is passed in if the API is implemented in C?  Probably using [PyCallable_Check](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyCallable_Check) and then [PyObject_Call](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Call).

Comment: more like what is the destiny of the foo object passed to register() and how is the design behind this register(), there is a data structure ? a chain of events ?

Comment: This depends on the API, some will use a data structure, others will store callbacks with the objects that trigger them.  For example a button might have an onclick attribute and you would register a callback using `button.onclick = some_callback`.